# How to improve the outputs of the Laravel `artisan` commands?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

When I run any Laravel `artisan` command in my terminal, I get the outputs like this:

[image]

How can I get rid of these unnecessary and useless outputs?

Comment: These are color codes. You're using a terminal that doesn't support them. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19520.

Comment: @ceejayoz There is a [temp solution](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19520#issuecomment-238941478) in the issue page you've mentioned, which is to pass the `--no-ansi` flag with every artisan command. It's a temp solution I can use for now. Thank you.